# Android 4.0.3 HTTP POST file to PHP server failed

Tags: http, post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am just upgrading my Android from 2.3.4 to 4.0.3, but find a problem when I want to post a file (around 2MB) to a php server through the http post method. But it looks like Android 4.0.3 does not work while Android 2.3.4 works well.

The following is part of my Android code to post a file:

```
private boolean postFile(String urlstr, String localpath, String uploadname) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, bytesUploaded = 0;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 2*1024*1024;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(localpath) );

        URL url = new URL(urlstr);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);

        // POST settings.
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

        os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + uploadname +"\"" + lineEnd);
        os.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fis.available();
        System.out.println("available: " + String.valueOf(bytesAvailable));
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        prog = 0;
        bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesUploaded += bytesRead;
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            prog = bytesUploaded/bytesAvailable;
            os.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fis.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesUploaded += bytesRead;
        }
        System.out.println("uploaded: "+String.valueOf(bytesUploaded));
        os.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        os.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        conn.setConnectTimeout(2000); // allow 2 seconds timeout.
        int rcode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (rcode == 200) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //String rmsg = conn.getResponseMessage();
        fis.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        return rcode == 200;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
02-02 22:38:34.626: W/System.err(5547): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-02 22:38:34.631: W/System.err(5547): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-02 22:38:34.631: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-02 22:38:34.631: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-02 22:38:34.636: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-02 22:38:34.641: W/System.err(5547):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-02 22:38:34.641: W/System.err(5547):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-02 22:38:34.641: W/System.err(5547):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-02 22:38:34.641: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
02-02 22:38:34.646: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-02 22:38:34.646: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-02 22:38:34.646: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-02 22:38:34.646: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-02 22:38:34.651: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
02-02 22:38:34.651: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
02-02 22:38:34.651: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
02-02 22:38:34.651: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-02 22:38:34.656: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
02-02 22:38:34.656: W/System.err(5547):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
02-02 22:38:34.656: W/System.err(5547):     at edu.socialsense.SocialsenseService.postFile(SocialsenseService.java:324)
02-02 22:38:34.661: W/System.err(5547):     at edu.socialsense.SocialsenseService.report(SocialsenseService.java:285)
02-02 22:38:34.661: W/System.err(5547):     at edu.socialsense.SocialsenseService.access$7(SocialsenseService.java:279)
02-02 22:38:34.661: W/System.err(5547):     at edu.socialsense.SocialsenseService$1.onReceive(SocialsenseService.java:79)
02-02 22:38:34.661: W/System.err(5547):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
02-02 22:38:34.661: W/System.err(5547):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-02 22:38:34.666: W/System.err(5547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 22:38:34.666: W/System.err(5547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 22:38:34.666: W/System.err(5547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
02-02 22:38:34.666: W/System.err(5547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 22:38:34.671: W/System.err(5547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 22:38:34.671: W/System.err(5547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-02 22:38:34.671: W/System.err(5547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-02 22:38:34.671: W/System.err(5547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I follow the code from step to step, I found the exception happened when the url connection tried to connect, say conn.connect() or conn.getOutputStream().

Please help me on this...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown.

You shouldn't do network operations on the main thread. This will lead to your app being unresponsive. Before Honeycomb you could get away with it, but Honeycomb and newer Android versions will check and throw the exception you're getting. See also [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) of the Android Developers API.

Answer (score 0):

From Android4.0 onwards "HttpUrlConnection" method uses "get" method by default.

If you add `SetDoOutput(true)"` property "POST" method will be called.

Bottom line is "Please remove `conn.setDoOutput(true);` with your code and then run.

Let me know if this solves ur problem.

Comment: Thanks @BalaK Taduri, but it looks like the code is still not works correct when I remove this line. And I received the same error listed above.